# Streaming Audio latency on android ICS and Jelly Bean is it real?

Tags: android, audio, streaming, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, latency

People on the net give latency numbers of around 88mS for Galaxy Nexus running ICS and 72mS for Nexus 7 running JB 4.1.1  I have tried with both AudioTrack and OpenES and found that I cannot get less than 140mS latency on either device.  Am I missing something?  I have set my output threads to URGENT_AUDIO priority, pass the audio in small chunks (eg 160 shorts) and use the minimum buffer size (in the AudioTrack case).

Are the quoted numbers only valid for short sounds played through SoundPool and not applicable to streaming PCM?  Just to be clear, I am talking about playback only not recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is androids dirty little secret. It is not fixed, all you need is an app, an ear, and a finger to find the truth.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems Galaxy Nexus running JB is the only option for low-latency streaming (40-60mS).